# Incrementing array access expression with no key

Tags: php

Why is this ok in PHP (7.3)? Is there any use case for it?

```php
<?php

$foo =  [10, 20, 30];
echo $foo[]++, "\n", ++$foo[], "\n", ++$foo[], "\n";
```

outputs:

```sh
php test.php

1
1
```

I expected a read error like below.

```php
<?php

$foo = [10, 20, 30];
$foo[] += 1; // No error either
$foo[] = $foo[] + 1; //PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use [] for reading in
```

Answer (score 6):

`$foo[]++` first creates a new, `null` entry in `$foo`, which is echo'ed, resulting in a a blank line (since `echo null;` outputs nothing). The new entry in `$foo` is then incremented, so `null` is type juggled to `0` as an integer, resulting in a value `1`.

`++$foo[]` creates another new, `null` entry in `$foo`, which in this case is incremented before being output, hence the two lines with `1` in them.

If you change your code to use `var_dump` instead of `echo` you can see this more clearly:

```
$foo =  [10, 20, 30];
var_dump($foo[]++);
var_dump(++$foo[]);
var_dump(++$foo[]);
var_dump($foo);
```

Output:

```
NULL
int(1)
int(1)
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(10)
  [1]=>
  int(20)
  [2]=>
  int(30)
  [3]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(1)
  [5]=>
  int(1)
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iWYfl)

Note that unlike incrementing `null`, which results in `1`, *decrementing* `null` has **no** effect (`var_dump(--$foo[])` outputs `null`). This behaviour is described in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Answer (score 2):

This strange pushing technique is something that I cannot imagine needing in a project and would be very likely to confuse future readers of the script.

From 3v4l.org, it seems this behavior is consistent from php7.2 and up.

The first increment is a post-increment, so the initial `$foo[]` which equals `null` is displayed before it is incremented.

The second two increments are pre-increments, so they are echoing the incremented value.

Incrementing `null` creates `1` which is echoed and stored as `1`.
Decrementing `null` creates `null` which is stored as `null` and echoed as an empty string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CjFPn))

```
$foo =  [10, 20, 30];
echo $foo[]++;
echo "\n---\n";
var_export($foo);
echo "\n---\n";
echo ++$foo[], "\n", --$foo[], "\n";
var_export($foo);
echo "\n===\n";
var_export(--$foo[]);
```

Output:

```
---
array (
  0 => 10,
  1 => 20,
  2 => 30,
  3 => 1,
)
---
1

array (
  0 => 10,
  1 => 20,
  2 => 30,
  3 => 1,
  4 => 1,
  5 => NULL,
)
===
NULL
```

Something that HAS changed since php7.3 is that `array_push()` will now accept a single parameter. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NI1Qu))

```
$foo = [];
array_push($foo);
var_export($foo);
```

The above snippet is effect-less -- it pushes no new element.  The count remains zero, but no Warning is generated from php7.3.